# API exception while calling 'DataWarehouseGetReportData' in C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, adobe-analytics

I am using `Omniture` api to download a report. The report is completed when I checked the status with `DataWarehouseCheckRequest` method. Now when I try to fetch the report using `DataWarehouseGetReportData` method, I get

`CommunicationException Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'DataWarehouseGetReportData`

Inner exception says

`The specified type was not recognized: name='data_warehouse_report_row', namespace='http://www.omniture.com/', at <rows xmlns=''>`

I am new with C# and the API both. Got no idea how to resolve this. Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to download a DW report the best option is to do it over http. This the standard way and is much more efficient.

The response to CheckRequest contains a DataURL. Use that to download the data.

Here is some c# sample code I am using for an almost identical API (Partner vs you Enterprise API) (note I'm no c# expert either, so you will need to do a code review on this).

```
        HttpWebResponse statusResponse = null;
        string response = "";
        StringBuilder sbUrl = new StringBuilder(dwrq.data_url);   // hardcode to variable "rest_url" for testing.
        HttpWebRequest omniRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sbUrl.ToString());
        string timecreated = generateTimestamp();
        string nonce = generateNonce();
        string digest = getBase64Digest(nonce + timecreated + secret);
        nonce = base64Encode(nonce);
        omniRequest.Headers.Add("X-WSSE: UsernameToken Username=\"" + username + "\", PasswordDigest=\"" + digest + "\", Nonce=\"" + nonce + "\", Created=\"" + timecreated + "\"");
        omniRequest.Method = "GET";  // Switched from POST as GET is the right HTTP verb in this case

        try
        {
            statusResponse = (HttpWebResponse)omniRequest.GetResponse();
            using (Stream receiveStream = statusResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    response = readStream.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Response is a TAB delimeted CSV structure. Printing to screen.");
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        Console.WriteLine("Ending REST...");
        Console.WriteLine("Ending ExportRequestSegmentedData...");
```

and the supporting methods

```
    /*** Here are the private functions ***/
    // Encrypting passwords with SHA1 in .NET and Java
    // http://authors.aspalliance.com/thycotic/articles/view.aspx?id=2 
    private static string getBase64Digest(string input)
    {
        SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
        ASCIIEncoding ae = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = ae.GetBytes(input);
        byte[] digest = sha.ComputeHash(data);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(digest);
    }

    // generate random nonce 
    private static string generateNonce()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int len = 24;
        string chars = "0123456789abcdef";
        string nonce = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            nonce += chars.Substring(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(random.NextDouble() * chars.Length)), 1);
        }
        return nonce;
    }

    // Time stamp in UTC string 
    private static string generateTimestamp()
    {
        return DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
    }

    // C#-Base64 Encoding 
    // http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=287324 
    public static string base64Encode(string data)
    {
        byte[] encData_byte = new byte[data.Length];
        encData_byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
        string encodedData = Convert.ToBase64String(encData_byte);
        return encodedData;
    }
```

Best of Luck! C.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I used this method and it worked like charm. Though I am not sure how this more efficient than usual SOAP requests, can you throw some light on this?

Comment: Hi @pearl67, it is more efficient because it is in a basic tab delimited format and is pretty simple. xml is very wordy, and we can be talking about data up to 2GB in size. so you get much more data in a tab delimited format then xml. also in the large xml format you may need to try a SAX parser to manage the memory requirements, so a lot more complexity IMHO. Best of luck

Comment: @pearl67, as this worked for you, can you accept this answer please.